# Lexicon-based text analysis. Any algorithm out there that does probabilistic category assignment?

Tags: nlp

I'm using a lexicon-based approach to text analysis. Basically I have a long list of words marked with whether they are positive/negative/angry/sad/happy etc. I match the words in the text I want to analyze to the words in the lexicon in order to help me determine if my text is positive/negative/angry/sad/happy etc.

But the length of the texts I want to analyze vary. Most of them are under 100 words, but consider the following example:

John is happy. (1 word in the category 'happy' giving a score of 33% for happy)

John told Mary yesterday that he was happy. (12.5% happy)

So comparing across different sentences, it seems that my first sentence is more 'happy' than my second sentence, simply because the sentence is shorter, and gives a disproportionate % to the word 'happy'.

Is there an algorithm or way of calculation you can think of that would allow me to make a fairer comparison, perhaps by taking into account the length of the sentence?

Comment: How happy would this be: "Barry was not at all happy with the food" ? Do you take account of this?

Comment: At the very least this has to reach syntactic level. You can begin considering getting clauses, and do other steps on those clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the issue of negation raised by `HappyTimeGopher`, you can simply divide the number of happy words in the sentence by the length of the sentence. You get:

John is happy. (1 word in the category 'happy' / 3 words in sentence = score of 33% for happy)

John told Mary yesterday that he was happy. (1/8 = 12.5% happy)

Keep in mind word-list based approaches will only go so far. What should be the score for "I was happy with the food, but the waiter was horrible"? Consider using a more sophisticated system--- the papers below are a good place to start your research:

- Choi, Y., & Cardie, C. (2008). Learning with compositional semantics as structural inference for subsentential sentiment analysis.
- Moilanen, K., & Pulman, S. (2009). Multi-entity sentiment scoring.
- Pang, B., & Lee, L. (2008). Opinion Mining and Sentiment Analysis.
- Pang, B., Lee, L., & Vaithyanathan, S. (2002). Thumbs up?: sentiment classification using machine learning techniques.
- Turney, P. D., & Littman, M. L. (2003). Measuring praise and criticism: Inference of semantic orientation from association.

Comment: Thank you for the handy references!

Answer (score 3):

As many pointed out, you have to go down to syntactic tree, something similar to [this work](http://erg.delph-in.net/logon).

[image: Syntax analysis]

Also, consider this:
John told Mary yesterday that **he** was happy.
John told Mary yesterday that **she** was happy.

The second one tells nothing about John's happiness, but naive algorithm would be confused quickly. So in addition to syntax parsing, *pronouns have to represent linking to the subjects*. In particular, that means that the algorithm should know that John is `he` and Mary is `she`.

Comment: Great diagram and explanation, I'll look into it as I go deeper into my work. Thanks!